# Websphere HTTP outbound connection pool usage

Tags: java, web-services, soap, websphere, connection-pooling

I have an application running on Websphere Application Server 6.1.0.43. And I'm having slowdown issues when thrying to invoke a remote service.

The slowdown is on the method findGroupAndGetConnection from the class outboundConnectionCache.

According to the IBM APAR [PK94494](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK94494):

> The delay occurs after the client-side JAX-RPC handler (if present) is invoked and before the actual SOAP message is sent to the provider.
>   Because the delay occurs in the IBM web services engine, this problem
>   can be difficult to detect.
>   A com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.*=all trace will show entries similar to these which repeat:
>
> [8/19/09 18:08:29:658 GMT] 00000047 OutboundConne 1   Enter:
>   WSWS3595I: Current pool size: 25. Connections-in-use size: 0.
>   Configured pool size: 25
>
> In addition, that same trace spec will show long delays in executing
>   the .findGroupAndGetConnection() method:
>
> [8/19/09 18:08:03:428 GMT] 00000047 OutboundConne >
>   OutboundConnectionCache.findGroupAndGetConnection()
>   WAITING_THREADS_THRESHOLD is 5 Entry
>
> [8/19/09 18:08:38:358 GMT] 00000047 OutboundConne <
>   OutboundConnectionCache.findGroupAndGetConnection() Exit

And they recommend the following:

> - Reduce the 'com.ibm.websphere.webservices.http.connectionPoolCleanUpTime' from
>     the default of 180 to 120 seconds
> - Increase the max connections 'com.ibm.websphere.webservices.http.maxConnection' property from
>     default of 25 to 50. This will also require increasing the web
>     container thread pool size to 100.

Before changing the default properties I decided to monitor the Web Container thread usage and I noticed that maximum thread pool size (50) is never reached, but the minimum pool size (10) is reached very often, forcing connections to be destroyed and recreated.

Running over the minimum pool size will cause this slowdown? Should I increase the minimum pool size? Is my problem something other than http outbound connection pool?

Comment: Can you try JVM argument -Xthr:noAdaptSpin ? I once saw this as a culrprit in a similar report.

Comment: I don't have access to the JVM. I'm using a monitoring tool to have access to this data, but I'll take a look at that, thank you.